# mySql Trigger AFTER INSERT Not Fireing?

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

Ok, I have a simple php chat app that works fine and saves messages into mySQL table.
But with time table gets more and more bigger so I want to add a trigger on every INSERT to clean the table. The problem is I'm creating the trigger from GUI in phpMyAdmin, the query itself works but the trigger isnt and when the trigger is present the messages also are not saved into database.

This is the trigger I'm trying to get to work:

```
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS `ClearChat`;
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost`
TRIGGER `ClearChat` AFTER INSERT ON `chat`
FOR EACH ROW DELETE FROM `chat` WHERE msg_id NOT IN ( 
    SELECT `msg_id` FROM (
        SELECT `msg_id` FROM `chat` 
        ORDER BY `msg_id` DESC
        LIMIT 5
)sub ORDER BY `msg_id` ASC )
```

The query from DELETE FROM etc. works fine when I run it into SQL statement

Comment: I've also marked one strange behavior. While the trigger above is active, when I try to insert messages from the app they are not inserted, BUT when i delete the trigger and try to insert messages they do go into the table BUT the msg_id is skipped for the number of failed insertion. Its almost like the messages got inserted and deleted by the trigger right after the insertion??

Comment: Do not use a trigger for this purpose. Use a MySQL event that deletes the data on a scheduled basis.

Comment: OK than if trgger is not possible I suppose that event will do the thing but this is problem that in future someone has so use a trigger? Are you saying that this is not possible with trigger?

Comment: Doing table maintenance on every insert is going to hurt performance. Also during peak insert activity you will be adding a lot of over head to the server. Using a trigger is easy it just aint a good idea. An event you can control and plan to use it at right times like running it during non peak hours. A trigger here is like using a screw driver to hammer in a nail. You will get it done just not the best tool for the job.

Comment: @Namphibian I'm thankful for the suggestion and I already set the event on daily basis. I am aware that event in this particular problem will do the job, but I cant ignore that triggers are one of the most important functions when working with databases. I just want to know in future projects should I use MS SQL or I can do the same job with mySQL or other free solutions. There are problems that you have to check some values on every inserts or updates... Some informations that are kept in database can be very sensitive you must agree.